# MySQL query performance tuning about financial year

Tags: mysql, performance, database-performance, query-performance, sqlperformance

I have a large table with around a 20 million records. the structure of the table with its indexes is:

```
CREATE TABLE `fact_ra` (
`replacement_record_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`product_tree_1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`product_tree_2` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`product_tree_3` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`product_tree_4` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`claim_owner` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`product_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`month` date DEFAULT NULL,
`m1` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m2` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m3` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m4` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m5` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m6` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m7` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m8` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m9` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m10` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m11` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m12` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m13` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m14` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m15` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m16` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m17` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m18` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m19` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m20` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m21` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m22` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m23` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m24` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m25` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m26` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m27` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m28` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m29` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m30` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m31` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m32` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m33` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m34` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m35` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m36` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m37` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m38` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m39` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m40` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m41` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m42` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m43` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m44` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m45` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m46` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m47` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m48` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m49` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m50` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m51` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m52` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m53` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m54` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m55` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m56` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m57` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m58` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m59` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`m60` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`replacement_record_id`),
KEY `idx_product_tree_1` (`product_tree_1`),
KEY `idx_product_tree_2` (`product_tree_2`),
KEY `idx_product_tree_3` (`product_tree_3`),
KEY `idx_product_tree_4` (`product_tree_4`),
KEY `idx_month` (`month`),
FULLTEXT KEY `fidx_claim_owner` (`claim_owner`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

and I am runing the following query:

```
select case when month(product_date) >= 4 then concat(year(product_date), \'-\', 
year(product_date)+1) else concat(year(product_date)-1,\'-\', year(product_date)) end as 
financial_year, sum(t1.m1) as m1, sum(t1.m2) as m2, sum(t1.m3) as m3, sum(t1.m4) as m4,    
sum(t1.m5) as m5, sum(t1.m6) as m6, sum(t1.m7) as m7, sum(t1.m8) as m8, sum(t1.m9) as m9, 
sum(t1.m10) as m10, sum(t1.m11) as m11, sum(t1.m12) as m12, sum(t1.m13) as m13, 
sum(t1.m14) as m14, sum(t1.m15) as m15, sum(t1.m16) as m16, sum(t1.m17) as m17, 
sum(t1.m18) as m18, sum(t1.m19) as m19, sum(t1.m20) as m20, sum(t1.m21) as m21, 
sum(t1.m22) as m22, sum(t1.m23) as m23, sum(t1.m24) as m24, sum(t1.m25) as m25, 
sum(t1.m26) as m26, sum(t1.m27) as m27, sum(t1.m28) as m28, sum(t1.m29) as m29, 
sum(t1.m30) as m30, sum(t1.m31) as m31, sum(t1.m32) as m32, sum(t1.m33) as m33, 
sum(t1.m34) as m34, sum(t1.m35) as m35, sum(t1.m36) as m36, sum(t1.m37) as m37, 
sum(t1.m38) as m38, sum(t1.m39) as m39, sum(t1.m40) as m40, sum(t1.m41) as m41, 
sum(t1.m42) as m42, sum(t1.m43) as m43, sum(t1.m44) as m44, sum(t1.m45) as m45, 
sum(t1.m46) as m46, sum(t1.m47) as m47, sum(t1.m48) as m48, sum(t1.m49) as m49, 
sum(t1.m50) as m50, sum(t1.m51) as m51, sum(t1.m52) as m52, sum(t1.m53) as m53, 
sum(t1.m54) as m54, sum(t1.m55) as m55, sum(t1.m56) as m56, sum(t1.m57) as m57, 
sum(t1.m58) as m58, sum(t1.m59) as m59, sum(t1.m60) as m60 from fact_ra t1
where month >= '2008-4-1' and month <= '2013-11-1' and claim_owner like '%test%'
and product_tree_1 = 'abc' group by financial_year
```

But the query takes a lot of time, here is the explain plan that I get:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                | key                | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ref  | idx_product_tree_1,idx_month | idx_product_tree_1 |   137   | const |    1 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

How to turning performance about this query, thanks

Comment: `m1..m60` --- It's... amazing

Comment: you've got one of the worst sql tuning scenario i've ever seen.

Comment: @Sebas: one day I've inherited a database which had the table names from `A` to `Z` (a single letter) and in every of it the columns followed the same convention (except `id` which was the only meaningful column name in the whole database)

Comment: @zerkms, that sounds promising. we should make a top 10...

Comment: Is altering the table schema an option?

Comment: @xavierzhao, Please use index on `product_date`.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Anderson With 20 million records, and likely application code depending on it? I wouldn't. (But I might well dump the table and load up a copy somewhere I could play with it.)

Comment: @Blade You should make that an answer; even if it's not the complete solution (which I think it might be), it's certainly going to help.

Comment: Also recommended: See if you can eliminate that LIKE comparison in the WHERE clause, or at the very least eliminate the leading `%` -- as it is, that has to do (m - (n-1)) string compares per row, where *m* is the length of that row's `claim_owner` value, and *n* is the length of the constant string in the LIKE test. Without the leading `%`, the string comparison only has to be done once.

Comment: @AaronMiller That's why I asked if it was an option. There's really no way to tell based on what he's provided if it's already a data dump for reporting or if it is actual part of transactional data. Looks like a data dump to me.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Anderson I'm sorry, I'm late, you can change the table schema, thanks for give me an idea

Comment: @AaronMiller Thanks for your suggestion, the value of `claim_owner` with multi-bytes character(Chinese character), it's split by `/` like this: `BU有效/BU无效/.../....`, so I didn't use full-text search(Chinese character supported not well), do you have a better way to query `claim_owner`? you can change the table schema, thanks

Comment: Sorry for my English ^_^

Comment: @Blade Thanks, I'm trying to create index on `product_date`, but it's so slowly

Comment: @zerkms I'm amazing too!!! any idear for me? thanks

Comment: Try changing the order of condition as we can get benefit of short circuit operators  `where product_tree_1 = 'abc' and month >= '2008-4-1' and month <= '2013-11-1' and claim_owner like '%test%' group by financial_year`. Also the you can claim_owner check condition as it causes quite a lot of delay in the query

Answer (score -1):

Here's some things that might help.

As xavierhao mentioned in the comments above, you should try an index on product_date.

```
ALTER TABLE `fact_ra` ADD INDEX `idx_product_date` (product_date);
```

If that does not improve performance enough, then you could try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `fact_ra` ADD financial_year char(4) AFTER product_date;
```

Then run an update to set financial year based on the logic you have above, so if its jan 2013, you'd set it to 2012 as that falls under last year.

Add an index on financial_year and try that out.

This way your group by doesn't have to deal with calculated values and can use the index directly.

If those don't help, post some more details and I'll see if I can assist further.

Comment: @Michael J. Anderson: `product_date` isn't even used in `WHERE`. What is the reason to cover it with index?

Comment: `financial_year char(4)` --- oh god, such a terrible advice

Comment: @xavierzhao: 1st suggestion - to stop using `LIKE '%foo%'` comparisons

Comment: @zerkms Sorry, this requirement is inevitably by our customers, what's the 2st suggestion or other improvements?

Comment: @xavierzhao: buy a better server then. They want to have non-optimizable condition - they pay for the better hardware that could load it. It's that simple.

Comment: @zerkms product_date was referenced in the group by before the edit. 'buy better hardware' is not helpful and doesn't attempt to address the actual problem. Based on the information provided, manipulating the table is a good starting point. I'd rather see the schema redesigned completely, but there isn't enough detail provided here for that.

Comment: @Michael J. Anderson: "product_date was referenced in the group by before the edit" --- `GROUP BY` is processed **after** `WHERE`. So if `WHERE` was performed without using indexes, then it's too late for indexes to appear somewhere in the query. So covering anything that appears in `GROUP BY` after the table fullscan makes no sense.

Comment: The most general way to satisfy a GROUP BY clause is to scan the whole table and create a new temporary table where all rows from each group are consecutive, and then use this temporary table to discover groups and apply aggregate functions (if any). In some cases, MySQL is able to do much better than that and to avoid creation of temporary tables by using index access.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html

Comment: I agree with @zerkms said, in fact, the query dose not use an index `finanical_year`

Comment: @Michael J. Anderson: after full scan was performed it's too late to use indexes. Please read somewhere how optimizer in DBMS work before you give performance optimizations advices. "MySQL is able to do much better than that and to avoid creation of temporary tables by using index access." --- right. If you don't have `WHERE` at all or if to perform `WHERE` the compatible index was used.